# Rearrange index of array to match other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays containing the same elements but in different order, like this:

```
var arr1 = [{name: 'Bob', age: 24}, {name: 'Mary',age: 45}, {random: props}]; 
var arr2 = [{name: 'Mary', age:45 }, {name: 'Bob',24}, {other: randomProps}];
```

In this case of course a simple reverse() would do the trick but it might be an array with 10 objects in a random order.

Since both arrays always contains some common properties (`name`) I should be able to rearrange one array to match the other based on `name`.

Any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: Can both arrays be rearranged, or does one have to be rearranged to the other with the other being unchanged?

Comment: If both the array contains same but  element in different  order.. Instead of arranging them and using it.. You can use any one of the array as is right??

Comment: I don't understand the question. If they contain the same elements why not duplicate the first list as opposed to reordering the second? Confused.

Comment: @timolawl, Hmm I guess both arrays can be rearranged as long as the end up with the same index for the name property. 
Reddy, Im not sure i understand
Andrew, They two totally different arrays that happens to have some common properties. The other properties, that are not common are needed so i can not duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this then? But this assumes that each object in the array has the name property.

```js
var arr1 = [{name: 'Bob', age: 24}, {name: 'Mary',age: 45}, {random: props}]; 
var arr2 = [{name: 'Mary', age:45 }, {name: 'Bob',24}, {other: randomProps}];

function sortArray(arr) {
 arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.name > b.name;
 }); 
}

sortArray(arr1);
sortArray(arr2);
```

Comment: Aha, it never occured to me to sort both the arrays like this. Thank you!

Comment: The OP doesn't want to sort by name, but rather sort so names are in the same order as the first array, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can scan the arranged array and search elements in the second array and put them in a new array.

```
new_array;
foreach(element in array_ordered)
{
    temp = search(element[name], array_unordered);
    if(temp != null)
        new_array.add(temp);
}
```